# Keyboard shortcuts not working in KDE 4.5.0

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts

My printscreen button doesn't work (it doesn't launch ksnapshot, but xev registers it's events just fine). Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? Old workarounds don't seem to be working.

**update**

`~/.xsession-errors` has this in it...

```
kded(17569)/kdecore (KLibrary) kde4Factory: The library "/usr/lib/kde4/kded_khotkeys.so" does not offer a qt_plugin_instance function.
kded(17569)/kdecore (KLibrary) kde3Factory: The library "/usr/lib/kde4/kded_khotkeys.so" does not offer an "init_kded_khotkeys" function.
kded(17569) Kded::loadModule: Could not load library "kded_khotkeys" . [ "Cannot load library /usr/lib/kde4/kded_khotkeys.so: (/usr/lib/libknewstuff3.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK6Attica8Provider17hasContentServiceEv)" ] 
systemsettings(18048)/khotkeys: Unable to start server org.kde.khotkeys (kded module) 
kded(17569)/kdecore (KLibrary) kde4Factory: The library "/usr/lib/kde4/kded_khotkeys.so" does not offer a qt_plugin_instance function.
kded(17569)/kdecore (KLibrary) kde3Factory: The library "/usr/lib/kde4/kded_khotkeys.so" does not offer an "init_kded_khotkeys" function
```

Comment: have you checked if your keyboard mapping is correct, with xev or xinput?

Comment: no... because I had it working in 4.4, and I know it didn't change. I really wish KDE would get around to fixing this massive fail that is it's keyboard shortcuts. This thing has been buggy since 4.1, it's about the only thing that worked in 4.0.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the correct keyboard is selected in the keyboard settings of KDE? You may just need to verify it has the correct keyboard selected, and an upgrade didn't inadvertantly detect an incorrect one.

Comment: @codewright @elmarco does the fact that I can create a shortcut and set it to the print key suggest that my keyboard settings are correct? it's a bug in kde that preventing it from working. Probably the same bug that was supposedly fixed in 4.4.

Comment: @codewright @elmarco I'll be honest that it's more likely that i'm missing a package than it is a problem with how my keyboard is set up. But really I just think it's that bug that was around from 4.1 'till they closed it in 4.4. I think it's not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by trying to rebuild *kdelibs* it told me *attica* wasn't installed, turned out it was corrupted. A reinstall fixed the issue.